# Linked list gets corrupted when I instantiate a Node immediately after calling append

Tags: c++, linked-list

I would like to know what may I be misunderstanding in the code below (the commented out lines). If I try to create the Node before going through the linked list, the values from root->next get messed up, from the second iteration onward.

The way the code is right now works, but I don't see why the other way doesn't.

```
template <class T>
class Node
{
    public:
        T data;
        Node* next;

        Node(T nodeData) : data(nodeData) { next = nullptr; }
        void append(T nodeData)
        {
            // If I uncomment this, I get the problem
            //Node newNode (nodeData);

            Node* insertionNode = this;
            while(insertionNode->next != nullptr)
            {
                insertionNode = insertionNode->next;
            }
            // Instead of using newNode, I must create the node here
            // insertionNode->next = &newNode;
            insertionNode->next = new Node(nodeData);
        }
};

int main()
{
    int testList[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    Node<int> rootNode(0);
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        rootNode.append(testList[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating `newNode`  on the stack. After `append`  has finished, it will no longer exist. By saying `new Node(nodeData);` you are essentially placing it on the heap, which gives you control over the objects life cycle.

Comment: No problem! It might also be worth having a little revise of dynamic memory http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/dynamic/